# How do I encode video in Visual C?

Tags: c, winapi, video-encoding

I have a video decrypter library that can decode an obsolete video format, and returns video frames in BMP and audio in WAV through callback functions. Now I need to encode a new video in any standard format under windows.

What might be the standard way to do this? I am using Win32/C. I guess Windows has its own encoding library and drivers and I don’t need to use FFMPEG. Any pointer to an example code or at least to a library to look at will be greatly helpful.

Edit: I accept. FFMPEG is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you have two native choices.

1. The old [Windows Multimedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713771(VS.85).aspx) library which is too ancient to seriously consider, but does have the [Video Compression Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713486(VS.85).aspx).
2. And then there's [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323(VS.85).aspx).

It's certainly doable through DirectShow, but you better enjoy COM programming and the concepts of Filters, Graphs, and Monikers (oh my). See this tutorial for a crash course:

[Recompressing an AVI File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms787544(VS.85).aspx)

And the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323(VS.85).aspx).

A simpler approach is indeed to use an library like [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) or [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc.html).

Answer (score 4):

To save yourself heartache, I echo Frank's suggestion of just using FFMPEG. Executing a separate FFMPEG process with the correct arguments will 100% be the easiest way to achieve your goals of encoding.

Your other options include:

[libavcodec](http://ffmpeg.org/) - The central library used in FFMPEG. I warn there don't appear to be many Windows binaries of libavcodec available, so you'd probably have to compile your own, which, at minimum, would require a Cygwin or MingW set up.

[ffdshow-tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) - A video codec library implemented as a DirectShow filter based on libavcodec. They do seem to have an [API](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/wiki/devel:controlling) for manipulating it, but it's a .NET library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the [VirtualDub](http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/) source code.  It's a well known encoder that uses VFW.  You may be able to get some ideas from that software.